# Clear and hide particular list item on radio button list selection

Tags: jquery, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

How to hide List item and clear text of a particular List item from a radio button list in asp.net using Jquery?

**What I tried:-**

```
$("#CPHM_rbtLstRating_1").hide();
```

**Issue:-** unable to hide list item text. Please suggest correct way to hide particular list item text.

Comment: can you share complete html for ul li and radio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check a radio button simply like this;

```
if($('#radio_button').is(':checked')) { 
    $(".someparticularli").empty(); //empty the selected item
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At runtime, the `RadioButtonList` will render and depending on the properties you have set it could produce drastically different HTML. Below is an example of the default, when `RepeatLayout="Table"`.

```
<table id="CPHM_rbtLstRating">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="CPHM_rbtLstRating_0" name="ctl00$CPHM$rbtLstRating" value="test" type="radio"><label for="CPHM_rblTest_0">test</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="CPHM_rbtLstRating_1" name="ctl00$CPHM$rbtLstRating" value="test" type="radio"><label for="CPHM_rblTest_1">test</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="CPHM_rbtLstRating_2" name="ctl00$CPHM$rbtLstRating" value="test" type="radio"><label for="CPHM_rblTest_2">test</label></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In order to remove everything associated with that particular radio button (not just the label), I suggest using jQuery's [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method.

> **Description:** For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
$("#CPHM_rbtLstRating_1").closest('tr').hide();
```

If your `RadioButtonList` has the property `RepeatLayout="OrderedList"` or `RepeatLayout="UnorderedList"` you'll want to find the closest `li` instead.

```
$("#CPHM_rbtLstRating_1").closest('li').hide();
```